# how to read json object when i don`t know the name of the key

Tags: javascript, json

in runtime i will have a dynamic dictionary object return to me

> e.g  var objectFromApi = {"A ":"I am A","B":"I am B","C":"I am C"}

i cannot do objectFromApi ["A"] to get the value, since i won`t able to know the key.

is there a way to print all the key and its value?

is there something like

```
for(j=0;j<objectFromApi.length;j++)
{
    console.debug(objectFromApi[j].Key +"  " + objectFromApi[j].Value);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for(var name in objectFromApi )
{
    if (objectFromApi.hasOwnProperty(name))
    {

    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V6t6Y/

Answer (score 3):

In ECMA 5 you can also use

```
var keys = Object.keys(objectFromAPi)
```

which will return

```
 ["A ", "B", "C"]
```

then you can iterate over the array like you normally would

```
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
     // do something with the value
     // objectFromApi[keys[i]] 
}
```